# The best NoSQL solution for the caching

Tags: caching, nosql, couchbase, distributed-caching

Recently I started to experience problems with my project's cache system based on Couchbase. It seems that I experience strange cache misses when I try to check if the object is already in the database. This results that the system fails to save the object in a prumary data store, because it is already in the database.

So,  I want to toy with another NoSQL solution to understand if it is a Couchbase problem or the problem in my caching layer. I know that most of the people use memcache for that, but memcache buckets are already integrated into Couchbecase, so I need something different.

The requirments are:

1. Storing the data in RAM
2. Ability to run on Windows
3. Integrated tools for monitoring (I really love Couchbase web interface)
4. Fast read and sufficient write speed
5. Ability to store objects in key-value maner (query support is not required)
6. Distributed caching
7. Free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about Redis?

There is a nice GUI for Redis at: https://github.com/steelThread/redmon

Comment: I was able to build Redis for windows, will try to put it in action :)